# How to change text of button when someone click on button in android

Tags: android

I am implementing one app where I want to change text of button when I will click on button.The following code i have tried so far,please tell me where am doing mistake.

```
private void shortlist(){

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>     () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("short response-------",response);
                if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                    btnSort.setText("shortlisted");
                    btnSort.setEnabled(false);
                }

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_BY,matri_id_by);
                params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_TO,matri_id_to);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: It is not working when click on button.

Comment: maybe that's because you didn't set onClickListener to the button?

Comment: Yes I have used onClickListener on button

Comment: btnSort =(Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btnshort);
        btnSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                matri_id_to=ids[position];
                shortlist();
            }
        });

Comment: does it show the toasts?

Comment: yes response is coming in Toast (Success) but setText() method is not working when click on button

Answer (score 0):

public class Profile_Match_custom_List  extends ArrayAdapter  {

```
private static final String url ="http://10.0.2.2/xp/shortlist1.php";
private static final String url1 = "http://10.0.2.2/xp/express_intrest.php";
private static final String KEY_MATRI_ID_TO="matriID_to";
private static final String KEY_MATRI_ID_BY="matriID_by";

SessionManager session;
public String matri_id_to, matri_id_by, str_gender;

String str;


private NetworkImageView imageView;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private final String[] ids;
private String[] ages;
private String[] heights;
public String[] communities;
public String[] castes;
public String[] educations;
public String[] occupations;
public String[] incomes;
public String[] pics;
public String[] locations;
public String[] shortlist;
public String[] expressinterest;
private Activity context;


public Profile_Match_custom_List(Activity context, String[] ids, String[] ages,
                                 String[] heights, String[] communities, String[] castes,
                                 String[] educations, String[] occupations, String[]incomes,
                                 String[]pics, String[] locations, String[] shortlist, String[] expressinterest) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_profile_match,ids);
    this.ids = ids;
    this.ages = ages;
    this.heights = heights;
    this.communities = communities;
    this.castes = castes;
    this.educations = educations;
    this.occupations = occupations;
    this.incomes = incomes;
    this.pics = pics;
    this.locations = locations;
    this.shortlist = shortlist;
    this.expressinterest = expressinterest;
    this.context = context;
}


static  class ViewHolder{
    public Button btnSort;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;


    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();


    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    final View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_profile_match, null, true);

    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(getContext());
    session.checkLogin();
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

    matri_id_by = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
    str_gender = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_GENDER);

    String url1 = "https://www.maangal.com/thumb/thumb_";
    String url = url1 + pics[position];

    imageView = (NetworkImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.offer_image);
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getContext()).getImageLoader();
    if(str_gender.equals("Male")) {
        imageLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, R.drawable.image, R.drawable.girl));
    }
    else {
        imageLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, R.drawable.image, R.drawable.boy));
    }
    imageView.setImageUrl(url,imageLoader);
    TextView textViewId = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

    textViewId.setText(ids[position]);

    textViewName.setText( ages[position]+" years"+" , "+heights[position]+" cm"+", "+communities[position]+" : "+castes[position]+" , "+educations[position]+" , "+occupations[position]+" , "+incomes[position]+", "+locations[position]);


    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), BlankActivity.class);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ids[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            i.putExtra("id", ids[position]);
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.btnSort =(Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btnshort);
     viewHolder.btnSort.setText("abhachfhfhf");
    final ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;
    viewHolder.btnSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {matri_id_to=ids[position];


           Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // shortlist();
            //Button b = (Button) v;
            finalViewHolder.btnSort.setText(shortlist[position]);
        }
    });

    Button btnChat =(Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btnchat);
    btnChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            matri_id_to=ids[position];
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"sent express intrest",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            express_Intrest();
        }
    });

    Button declineButton = (Button)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
    declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
    return listViewItem;
}

private void shortlist(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>     () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("short response-------",response);
            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                //btnSort.setText("shortlisted");
               // btnSort.setEnabled(false);
            }

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+matri_id_to, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_BY,matri_id_by);
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_TO,matri_id_to);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void express_Intrest(){
    StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url1, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.e("response",response);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_BY,matri_id_by);
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_TO,matri_id_to);

            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest1);
}
```

}

Comment: I used this code where the button text is changed on click but when I scrolling it the text is changed at previous text. Can anyone help me what should I do